# Akka HTTP, marshalling POJO

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I'm using Akka HTTP and the Jackson marshaller but I haven't been able to figure out how to marshal a POJO to a `HttpEntity`. My use case is quite simple really, I want to serialize a POJO to JSON and use it as the payload of a HTTP request to a 3rd party API.

Here's what I would like to be able to do:

```
HttpRequest.POST("/foo").withEntity(Jackson.marshaller(), Foo.class)
```

Alas seems there is no such a way.

Comment: Show us what you've tried?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov added a clarficiation thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is the best way, but you can achieve it under java by doing:

```
String json = ObjectMapperProvider.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload);
Http.get(system).singleRequest(HttpRequest.POST("url").withEntity(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON, json);
```

You do need an external ObjectMapper though, since the one inside Jackson.xxx is private.